# The equation $x^2+ax+(b+2)=0$ has real roots. Find the minimum value of $a^2+b^2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

The equation $x^2+ax+(b+2)=0$ has real roots. Find the minimum value of $a^2+b^2$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We the discriminant $\ge0$ $$\implies a^2-4(b+2)\iff a^2\ge4(b+2)$$

$$a^2+b^2\ge4b+8+b^2=(b+2)^2+4\ge4$$

Comment: Your solution is correct, but it has its drawback. It works only with quadratic equation. If you have higher degree polynomial, you must use CS inequality.

Comment: @Kf-Sansoo, Can you plz.. corroborate your statement with one example?

Comment: Using the solution I posted above, you can infact make your own equation, and even set your own conditions on the coefficients which satisfy your minimum values. There are plenty of examples using this idea.

Comment: Can you give an example of how a^2+b^2 can equal 4 as I got that it must be greater than 4?

Comment: @las, Assuming $b$ is real, $(b+2)^2\ge0$

Comment: Doesn't the discriminant have to be strictly greater than 4 because if it is 0, than there is only one root? The question asks for roots. So a^2+b^2>(b+2)^2+4>=4. So a^2+b^2>4?

Comment: @las, Not one root, two roots having the same value

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yep, my bad, thank you so much for the help :).

Answer (score 0):

In general this type of question can be settled by the use of Cauchy - Schwarz inequality as follows: $x^2+2 = -ax - b \implies (x^2+2)^2 = (ax+b)^2 \leq (x^2+1)(a^2+b^2)\implies a^2+b^2 \geq \dfrac{(x^2+2)^2}{x^2+1} = \dfrac{((x^2+1) + 1)^2}{x^2+1}\geq 4$, by the well-known AM-GM inequality $(t+1)^2 \geq 4t, t = x^2+1 $  in this case.